# How to print elements of array line by line and select each individual line with Ruby Curses?

Tags: ruby, curses

I am currently print lines 0-3 in Ruby Curses.  I also created an array with animal names.
My program currently outputs

```
dog + 0cat + 0bird + 0rat + 0
dog + 1cat + 1bird + 1rat + 1
dog + 2cat + 2bird + 2rat + 2
dog + 3cat + 3bird + 3rat + 3
```

I want it to output something like

```
dog  + 0
cat  + 1
bird + 2
rat  + 3
```

Is there a way to list each element of the array on a different line and be able to select each individual line?

Here is the function I am working on

```
def draw_menu(menu, active_index=nil)
  4.times do |i|
    menu.setpos(i + 1, 1)
    menu.attrset(i == active_index ? A_STANDOUT : A_NORMAL)

    arr = []
    arr << "dog"
    arr << "cat"
    arr << "bird"
    arr << "rat"

    arr.each do |item|

      menu.addstr "#{item} + #{i}"
    end
  end
end
```

I have tried using arr.each and arr.each_index but it gives me the same output.

Here is the complete program.

**UPDATE**

The below makes the menu look how I want but when pressing 'w' or 's' to scroll through the menu, it selects all 4 elements at the same time.  Is there a way to make it where only 1 element can be selected at a time?

```
require "curses"
include Curses

init_screen
start_color
noecho

def draw_menu(menu, active_index=nil)
  4.times do |i|
    menu.setpos(1, 1)
    menu.attrset(i == active_index ? A_STANDOUT : A_NORMAL)

    arr = []
    arr << "dog"
    arr << "cat"
    arr << "bird"
    arr << "rat"

    arr.each_with_index do |element, index|
      menu.addstr "#{element} + #{index}\n"
    end    
  end
end

def draw_info(menu, text)
  menu.setpos(1, 10)
  menu.attrset(A_NORMAL)
  menu.addstr text
end

position = 0

menu = Window.new(7,40,7,2)
menu.box('|', '-')
draw_menu(menu, position)
while ch = menu.getch
  case ch
  when 'w'
    draw_info menu, 'move up'
    position -= 1
  when 's'
    draw_info menu, 'move down'
    position += 1
  when 'x'
    exit
  end
  position = 3 if position < 0
  position = 0 if position > 3
  draw_menu(menu, position)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what that `4.times` was trying to do, but I think it was setting the same text 4 times into the same position on the screen. For each of the 4, if the current set of 4 items was the same as `active_index`, you'd set all 4 of them to the same style (`A_STANDOUT` instead of `A_NORMAL`).

What seems to be working for me and what I assume was intended is something like:

```
def draw_menu(menu, active_index=nil)
  %w(dog cat bird rat).each_with_index do |element, index|
    menu.setpos(index + 1, 1)
    menu.attrset(index == active_index ? A_STANDOUT : A_NORMAL)

    menu.addstr("%-4s + #{index}" % element)
  end

  menu.setpos(5, 1) # set the cursor on the line after the menu items
end
```

and then in your `draw_info` I couldn't see where the text was being output, but if I changed it to `setpos(5, 1)` it became visible on the line after the menu:

```
def draw_info(menu, text)
  menu.setpos(5, 1)
  menu.attrset(A_NORMAL)
  menu.addstr text
end
```

Comment: Question: What does the %-4s do?  I noticed if I change the 4s to another number, it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: Oh, that left-justifies the words and makes sure they all take up at least 4 spaces for instance with "%-4s" is looks like `rat--+ 3` and "%-8s" it becomes `rat------+ 3` (using dashes instead of spaces, since SO condenses spaces...that part isn't necessary, it was just bugging me while I was playing around with the example that things didn't line up...you could keep that line as `menu.addstr "#{element} + #{index}"` and be fine